# Submodularity property of trace of inverse matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, traces, tag-removed

$\newcommand{\tr}{\operatorname{tr}}$Does submodularity property hold for the trace of a positive-definite hermitian matrix?

I.e., does given any real symmetric positive-definite matrices $X,A,B$
$$
\tr X^{-1} + \tr(X+A+B)^{-1} \geq \tr(X+A)^{-1} + \tr(X+B)^{-1}
$$
hold?

**UPD:** I have checked it numerically, it appears that it does not hold for the following matrices:
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
X &= \begin{pmatrix} 0.08151549 & 0.05234424\\ 0.05234424 & 0.17050588 \end{pmatrix} \\
A &= \begin{pmatrix} 0.29185525 & 0.29699319\\ 0.29699319 & 0.30792421 \end{pmatrix} \\
B &= \begin{pmatrix} 0.65213446 & 0.43711443\\ 0.43711443 & 0.2932183 \end{pmatrix}
\end{split}
\end{equation}

Answer (score 4):

This submodularity property is known to not hold, as the OP has found out already. However, I'd like to mention the following observation:

Let $f$ be defined on $(0,\infty)$ such that $-f'$ is operator monotone (i.e., for $A\le B \implies f'(A) \ge f'(B)$), then
\begin{equation*}
\operatorname{Tr} f(A+B+C)+\operatorname{Tr} f(A) \le \operatorname{Tr} f(A+B)+\operatorname{Tr} f(A+C).
\end{equation*}

**Example:** the above inequality holds for $f(t)=t^p$ for $p\in (0,1)$.

Comment: I guess the last one is $\text{trace}f(A+C)$; right?

Comment: You are welcome! BTW do you have a reference for this inequality?